# Huawei map seems to be initialized on second time

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

I do have an android app which is adjusted to be released at huawei store.
Here is the initialization snippet:

```
if (areGoogleServicesAvailable()) {
      // google map here
} else {
      MapsInitializer.initialize(this)
      val mapFragment =
                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapHuawei) as com.huawei.hms.maps.SupportMapFragment
      mapFragment.getMapAsync {
          mapHuawei = it

          mapHuawei.update()
      }
}
```

This code runs in onCreate method of an activity. Now, if I open the activity for the first time since app being started, the map isn't shown, `getMapAsync` isn't triggered at all and in logs I can observe:

```
2023-05-15 12:32:00.429 11025-11025 HmsMapKit_...ragment_13 some.app              E  MapsInitializer is not initialized.
```

But starting from second time I open the activity, everything works as expected, `getMapAsync` is triggered and works further. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like moving `MapsInitializer.initialize(this)` to `application.onCreate` solves the issue